# Who is more important for Devi? - Her consort or son?

Tags: devi, shakti, shaktism, devi-bhagavata-purana

Whom does Devi love more? Her consort or her Children? Please don't say both! Please.Say only one. Devi once said to devtas that she can even give her life for her child. And please provide, if events from scriptures are available.For humanly mother, her child is everything but what about Devi? Does she love her child the most?

Comment: For a mother child is everything, so is it for Supreme mother. There is no doubt about it.

Comment: 

Comment: There is no difference between devi and her consort. So, on children only.